# Problem in fillRgn function

Tags: delphi, region

I am working with delphi. After I got a solution of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090645/combinergn-not-working) problem, Now I want the boundary of that combined region. Is there any easy solution?
Thank You.

**Edit:**
Boundary means the outer most points of region. My region is a polygon region and I want the points of that polygon.

Comment: You haven't described a problem with FillRgn at all. Please tell what problem you have. What do you mean by "the boundary" of a region, and what do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is and what you need to do with the region.

You can use [GetRgnBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144921%28VS.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the region's bounding rectangle, or [GetRegionData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144920%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the dimensions of the rectangles that make up the region.

For drawing the region, see [FillRgn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162720%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [FrameRgn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144839%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) APIs.

Comment: Yes, this can be done and by accessing each rectangle I can get boundary. I also solve it using floodfill algorithm. Thanx.